# How do I create a LoadBalancer service over Pods created by a ReplicaSet/Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using a ReplicaSet to manage my pods and I try to expose these pods with a service. The Pods created by a ReplicaSet have randomized names.

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
master                 2/2     Running   0          20m
worker-4szkz           2/2     Running   0          21m
worker-hwnzt           2/2     Running   0          21m
```

I try to expose these Pods with a Service, since some policies restrict me to use `hostNetwork=true`. I'm able to expose them by creating a `NodePort` service for each Pod with `kubectl expose pod worker-xxxxx --type=NodePort`.

This is clearly not a flexible way. I wonder how to create a Service (LoadBalancer type maybe?) to access to all the replicas dynamically in my ReplicaSet. If that comes with a Deployment that would be perfect too.

Thanks for any help and advice!

**Edit:**

I put a label on my ReplicaSet and a NodePort type Service called `worker` selecting that label. But I'm not able to `ping worker` in any of my pods. What's the correct way of doing this?

Below is how the `kubectl describe service worker` gives. As the `Endpoints` show the pods are picked up.

```
Name:                     worker
Namespace:                default
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 tag=worker
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.106.45.174
Port:                     port1  29999/TCP
TargetPort:               29999/TCP
NodePort:                 port1  31934/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.3:29999,10.40.0.2:29999
Port:                     port2  29996/TCP
TargetPort:               29996/TCP
NodePort:                 port2  31881/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.3:29996,10.40.0.2:29996
Port:                     port3  30001/TCP
TargetPort:               30001/TCP
NodePort:                 port3  31877/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.3:30001,10.40.0.2:30001
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Did you try adding a label to your deployment, something line `app: worker`, and creating a service with selector `app: worker`? That service should act like a load balancer in front of all the pods with that label.

Comment: @bserdar I created a type `NodePort` Service with the matching selectors and the Service is showing the worker Pods in `Endpoints`. But I'm not able to `ping worker` in master (`worker` is the Service name). Do you know am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: That service name will not be visible outside the cluster. The name should be visible to all the pods in the cluster. Since it is a node port, any worker should have that port open, and you can access it using workernode:port. If you need to expose that service outside the cluster, you either need an ingress, or you need an external load balancer pointing to all workernode:port nodes.

Comment: @bserdar Sorry I edited the `kubectl get pods` output. The `master` is a pod in k8s cluster so I expect it to be able to talk to the worker pods through that service. I added an edit of the service port forwarding. Am I not ping-ing the correct ports? Thanks!

Comment: What kube-proxy mode are you using, iptables or ipvs? If it is iptables mode, the service is not pingable since the iptables rule doesn't have a match for icmp traffic. Try telnet worker 29999

Comment: @HangDu That's a great point! I'm using iptable and `curl` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Believe that you can optimize this a bit by using Deployments instead of ReplicaSets (This is now the standard way), i.e you could have a deployment as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Then your service to match this would be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  # This is the important part as this is what is used to route to 
  # the pods created by your deployment
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```